# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, openssl

I get the error message in the question's title, or to be exact I get this message

```
  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl'
  (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl (/usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl: 
  cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), 
  /usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl.so: cannot 
  open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown
```

My real issue with this is that it only occurs sometimes and not always. In one second a request works and in the other, I get a 500 internal error with this message on the same request.

This started to occur after I enabled the apache `proxy` and `proxy_wstunnel` mods but could also have been an `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get update`.

From `phpinfo();`:

> - Version: PHP Version 7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
> - OpenSSL support    enabled
> - OpenSSL Library Version    OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27    Mar 2018
> - OpenSSL Header Version     OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018
> - Openssl default config     /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

If you need futher information feel free to task.

Edit:

From apache `error.log`

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl (/usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> [Fri Apr 20 06:25:01.973125 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2872] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Fri Apr 20 06:25:01.973154 2018] [core:notice] [pid 2872] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>
> [Fri Apr 20 06:34:04.715749 2018] [php7:error] [pid 3490] [client 5.146.199.236:41654] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php on line 414. in /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()\n#1 /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(135): yii\web\Response->send()\n#2 /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(262): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException))\n#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php on line 366
>
> [Fri Apr 20 06:34:58.208208 2018] [php7:error] [pid 3486] [client 5.146.199.236:41681] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php on line 414. in /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()\n#1 /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(135): yii\web\Response->send()\n#2 /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(262): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException))\n#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html_back/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php on line 366

Comment: Check and post your apache logs.

Comment: @MikeStratton appended the content of `var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: In the terminal type: "sudo openssl -v" (without quotes) and post results.

Comment: `sudo openssl -v` did not work, but `sudo openssl version` returns `OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018`

Comment: It looks like your apt-get update might have removed the version of openssl you were using before the update.

Comment: Pew, any idea how to fix that? And prevent it from happening again? I'm not that much of a unix person.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169408/discussion-between-mike-stratton-and-fussel).

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem.

It seems like i created it by manually enable

```
extension=openssl
```

in the php.ini. After disable it again everything looked fine

```
php -i | grep -i openssl
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.1.0g
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```