# Severity: Core Warning, PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' message

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, openssl

Sometimes this error appears when I open one of the pages of my site. My server os is ubuntu and i use Codeigniter and Php. How can i fix this?

Full message:

```
Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl (/usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: ۰

Backtrace:
```

I also tried this solution but the problem was not solved:
[PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936034/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-openssl-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Check if you openssl installed: `sudo openssl version`

Comment: version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g

Comment: Create a file phpinfo.php and add this `<?php phpinfo();?>` and open the file in your browser. Now Check if openssl module is loaded and enabled for your server.

Comment: I checked. Yes OpenSSL support is enabled.

Comment: after updating .ini file, did you restarted your services/server?

Comment: Yes i do. I rebooted the server.